# Docker: how to link host to container with the "link" option?

Tags: docker

I understand that it's possible to expose host to container manually, using the docker bridge network. But how can I make life easier to accomplish the linking by using the `--link` switch?

For example, I want to connect the database running on the host system from a container. One way to do it is to manually set the connection destination of the app in the container to the IP address of the host on the docker bridge network (`docker0` by default). Many docker images however provides an easy way to just use `--link` to connect to a database. How can I accomplish it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Docker links are exclusively for container-to-container communication.

To expose ports elsewhere, you'll need to use `-P` or `-p`.

Comment: I actually meant the reverse way: expose host to container.

Comment: Same deal. Links won't help you here.

Comment: Possibility to expose host to container discussed here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143